# Multi friend selector and authentication dialog in PageTab app

Tags: authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, selector, friend

i have created a page tab app for which i have set all the parameters under Auth Dialog in the app settings.
Now when i send a friend request through my app, and my friend clicks on the app request, he is able to see the authentication box describing the app and the permissions requested etc.
But if anyone visits my page on which i have added the app, and clicks on the app from there, it directly takes the user to the page tab without displaying the auth box.
Is this how it is supposed to work from a page? is it possible to display the auth box for a user coming to the app from a page?

Secondly, i have added a multi friend selector which opens by default in a popup as it is supposed to.
Is it possible to display it in the page itself instead of a popup?
I tried adding the display: 'page' option but it din work.

I have used the same code from : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

```
... 
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>


<p>
  <input type="button"
    onclick="sendRequestToRecipients(); return false;"
    value="Send Request to Users Directly"  />
  <input type="text" value="User ID" name="user_ids" />
  </p>
<p>
<input type="button"
  onclick="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(); return false;"
  value="Send Request to Many Users with MFS" />
</p>

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : XXXXXXXXXXX,
    status     : true, 
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    oauth      : true,
  });
};
(function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; 
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {
       return;
       }
   js = d.createElement('script');
   js.id = id; 
   js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
</script>

<script>
function sendRequestToRecipients() {
        var user_ids = document.getElementsByName("user_ids")[0].value;
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'My Great Request',
          to: user_ids, 
        }, requestCallback);
      }

      function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'My Great Request'
        }, requestCallback);
      }

      function requestCallback(response) {
        // Handle callback here
      }
</script>
...
```

Any help in this regard would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this how it is supposed to work from a page?

Yes. Authenticated referrals don’t work when the app is accessed from a page directly.

> is it possible to display the auth box for a user coming to the app from a page?

Of course – analyze the signed_request parameter, and react accordingly (meaning, display the auth dialog yourself, server- or client-side).